# AccessControlException: access denied - ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader") -Calling ASMX webservice through JNLP

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start, accesscontrolexception

I'm trying to call asmx webservice from Java, I had created jar file and refered this in JNLP.. but when I try to call, it gives this err,

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkCreateClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCreateClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.PsuedoSystemClassLoader.<init>(PsuedoSystemClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.JDK12Hooks.findSystemClassLoader(JDK12Hooks.java:215)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.JDK12Hooks.<clinit>(JDK12Hooks.java:73)
```

Comment: If common discovery (whatever that is) is supposed to work is supposed to play with SecurityManagers then it should insert a `doPrivileged` between the static initialiser and create a class loader. Bizarrely static initialisers are not called with full permissions (it appears nobody thought about it). It may just be that some relevant code is not signed/trusted - difficult to tell from this.